# point cloud development on PCL

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, point-cloud-library, openni

For a long time [opencv](http://opencv.org/) has been (and still is,) the main infrastructure for 2d development.

When going 3d, [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) is the natural choise: it has vast range of algorithms implemented, online API documentation, and the backbone of the industry's leading companies.

That said, How can it be that the last binary is for IDE 5 years ago?(!!!) last update was in 2013 (probably due to the [death of OPENNI](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/194-kinect/7004-openni-to-close-.html), thank you Apple), the implementation is obsolete , and I am not even talking about c++1x, nevertheless the futuristic [compute capability 5.x](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#compute-capability-5-x).

Is PCL a dead project? are there's any predecessors?

Comment: Unfortunately, PCL is *not* backed by any "industry's leading companies". It's maintained on purely volunteer basis, and it so happened that none of the volunteering maintainers are interested in Microsoft products. So your options are: switch to Linux or compile from source on Windows.

Comment: very relevant question given the uncertain enviroment of PCL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too work with PCL and find the outdated libraries frustrating. However as PhilLab mentioned the GitHub page is still active.

**HOWEVER:** Thanks to Tsuksa Sugiura there exists a perfect pre-built [package](http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1794&lang=en) for Windows + VS2015. He even maintains this and updates it. Both x86 and x64.

**ALSO** it is possible to use 1.8.0 RC2 on the NVidia Tegra platforms, such as the Jetson TX1. here the CMake system is working relatively well.

**AND** ROS supports it (again defaults to 1.7.2, but can run on 1.8.x)

So to conclude; sure no one is packing it into tidy releases, but the package is slowly getting advanced. And it kind of is our only choice...

```
Also to the moderators: I would have commented this on PhilLab's answer as I feel this doesn't dignify a new answer... but on this strange community you can answer before being able to comment. Sorry.
```

Comment: Damn it, I would've gotten all the upvotes if it weren't for SO's role management :-P Upvoted, though. Tsuksa Sugiura 's site seems to be down

Comment: I still don't understand SO's choice. The link appears to be working, regardless here is a direct raw link: http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl18/

Answer (score 2):

I share your frustration with the outdated prebuilts (outdated both in IDE version and PCL version) but the project is still quite active on GitHub: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/commits/master.

The [release cycle](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases) seems to be quite lengthy but the commits come in steadily

**Edit:** [Release 1.8.0 is in preparation](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1373) and the lack of Windows builds is because the [lack of a Windows programmer](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1358)

**Edit (06/2018):** The newest versions include windows prebuilds

Answer (score 0):

Now the best option to use PCL on windows is using the vcpkg package management system to manage the dependencies and binaries.